# ajax request not returning the result

Tags: plugins, ajax

i am using custom plugin to display the values on the wordpress admin side..

My Jquery html file is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery("#searchsubmit").click( function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var data = jQuery("#eventname").val();
                    var city =  jQuery("#city").val();
                    var date =  jQuery("#datepicker").val();

                    jQuery.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: './admin-ajax.php',
                            data:{action:'my_action',test:data,test1:city,test2:date},
                            dataType: 'html',                                   
                            success: function(response) {
                                alert(response);
                            }
                           });
                            });

                    });
                </script>
```

My Plugin File is

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

```
function my_action_callback(){

        $name = $_POST['test'];
        $city = $_POST['test1'];
        $date = $_POST['test2'];

        if ($date != '') {
            $enddate = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date));
            $dates_sql = " AND start_date <= '$date' ";
            }
            if ($city != '' && $city != -1) 
            $destination_sql = "AND venue = '$city'";
            if ($name != '' && $name != -1) 
                $origincity_sql = "AND event_name = '$name'";

        $query = " SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE event_id!='' " . $dates_sql . " " . $destination_sql . " " . $origincity_sql . " ORDER BY start_date DESC ";

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query) or die(mysql_error());    

        foreach ($results as $row)
        {
            $message  = "<tr><td align='center' id = 'username'>".$row->username."</td><td align='center' id = 'eventname'>".$row->event_name."</td><td align='center' id = 'venue'>". $row->venue."</td><td align='center' id = 'email'>".$row->email."</td><td align='center' id = 'misseddays'>".$row->missed_days."</td><td align='center' id = 'paymentstatus'>".$row->payment_mode."</td><td align='center' id = 'amountpaid'>".$row->amount_paid."</td><td align='center' id = 'amountbalance'>".$row->amount_balance."</td><td align='center' id = 'mailsent'>".$row->mail."</td></tr>";
        }  

        echo $message;
        exit();
    }
```

i am not getting the response into the jquery html file despite it is returning -1 as response
any changes to be done please help.stuck today on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the Wordpress ajax API correctly, see [Ajax in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Tha action parameter defines a function callback for `wp_aja_*` action hook, not the name of a file:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
//Uncomment next line if you want the ajax action enable in the frontend
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb;
    $name = $_POST['test'];
    $city = $_POST['test1'];
    $date = $_POST['test2'];

    if ($date != '') {
        $enddate = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date));
        $dates_sql = " AND start_date <= '$date' ";
    }
   if ($city != '' && $city != -1) {
        $destination_sql = "AND venue = '$city'";
   }
   if ($name != '' && $name != -1) {
            $origincity_sql = "AND event_name = '$name'";
   }

   $query = " SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE event_id!='' " . $dates_sql . " " . $destination_sql . " " . $origincity_sql . " ORDER BY start_date DESC ";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query) or die(mysql_error());    

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $message  = "<tr><td align='center' id = 'username'>".$row->username."</td><td align='center' id = 'eventname'>".$row->event_name."</td><td align='center' id = 'venue'>". $row->venue."</td><td align='center' id = 'email'>".$row->email."</td><td align='center' id = 'misseddays'>".$row->missed_days."</td><td align='center' id = 'paymentstatus'>".$row->payment_mode."</td><td align='center' id = 'amountpaid'>".$row->amount_paid."</td><td align='center' id = 'amountbalance'>".$row->amount_balance."</td><td align='center' id = 'mailsent'>".=$row->mail."</td></tr>";
    }  
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($message);
    exit;
}

?>
```

You may also take a look to [wp_send_json](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json), [wp_send_json_error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_error) and [wp_send_json_success](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success).

Comment: i defined the api in the plugin file.i am doing it on the backend.its returning to wordpress option page ..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean with "I defined the API...". Can you expand? I think that you are putting the code I posted in the file my_action.php but you are not including the file anywhere, so the code in my_action.php is not executed. Try to include the code I posted in the main file of the plugin or in the functions.php file of your theme.

Comment: its worked i missed the functionality to be placed under theme functions.php file.Thanks @Cybmeta